# appearanceForTraitCollection: returns nil

Tags: ios, uiappearance

Considering the following lines:

```
UITraitCollection *traitCollection = [UITraitCollection traitCollectionWithHorizontalSizeClass:UIUserInterfaceSizeClassCompact];
UITabBarItem *compactAppearance = [UITabBarItem appearanceForTraitCollection:traitCollection];
UITabBarItem *standardAppearance = UITabBarItem.appearance;
```

`compactAppearance` is always `nil`, while standard appearance is working fine.

[image: Debug Info]

I have tried with different trait configuration without any success. Is there anything I am missing here.

I have tried with UIButton and it seems to be working. Is this just unsupported for the UITabBarItem? Then how would I cleanly defined different fonts for Compact vs Regular TabBarItems?